# ORA-00001: unique constraint DJANGO ORACLE

Tags: django, oracle

By Sql Developer, I made an insert into  and in my page django shows it correctly, but when I enter another value through the page, I get the error that the id already exists, because the record was entered from the developer not from django, how can I fix this? to do a bulk upload from developer?

Comment: Check how `Django` controls the assigment of the `id`s. If sequence is used (as it should), you must use *the same sequence* while inserting the additional rows and everything will be fine...

Comment: Thank you very much, I just had to do the inserts adding the sequence, in my case: INSERT INTO <TABLENAME> VALUES (<SEQUENCENAME.NEXTVAL>) AND IT ALREADY WORKS CORRECTLY